# Generic protocol as an argument fails with "Cannot invoke with an argument list of type" error

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have this code in a playground, but it does not compile. The error is `Cannot invoke 'actionDispatcher' with an argument list of type '(uiEvent: MyEvent)'`.

This is the snippet of the code:

```
import UIKit

protocol CircuitUiEvent {}

protocol CircuitInteractor {

    associatedtype UiEvent: CircuitUiEvent

    func actionDispatcher(uiEvent: UiEvent)
}

enum MyEvent: CircuitUiEvent {
    case hello

}

class MyInteractor: CircuitInteractor {

    typealias UiEvent = MyEvent

    func actionDispatcher(uiEvent: MyEvent) {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

extension CircuitInteractor {

    func myTestFunction() {
        let uiEvent = MyEvent.hello
        actionDispatcher(uiEvent: uiEvent) <--- this line throws the error
    }
}

let interactor = MyInteractor()
interactor.myTestFunction()
```

Any ideas? What I need is an enum that conforms to a protocol to be passed as an argument, so I can have a simple API definition that, depending on where it will be used, or the model behind it, it can use different switch statements.

Comment: Your extension is on `CircuitInteractor` but there is no guarantee that `MyEvent` is a valid type for `CircuitInteractor.UiEvent`.  You would either need to extend `MyInteractor` or add a `where UiEvent == MyEvent` clause to your extension.

Comment: I think you can delete `typealias UiEvent = MyEvent`, can't you? The declaration of `func actionDispatcher` resolves the generic.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems like you need to move `myTestFunction` to `MyInteractor` class since it's a function that uses concrete event types while `CircuitInteractor` uses general protocol. Perhaps, something like this would make sense?

```
protocol CircuitUiEvent {}

protocol CircuitInteractor {
  associatedtype UiEvent: CircuitUiEvent
  func actionDispatcher(uiEvent: UiEvent)
}

extension CircuitInteractor {
  func actionDispatcher(uiEvent: UiEvent) {
    print(uiEvent)
  }
}

enum MyEvent: CircuitUiEvent {
  case hello
}

class MyInteractor: CircuitInteractor {
  typealias UiEvent = MyEvent
  func myTestFunction() {
    self.actionDispatcher(uiEvent: .hello)
  }
}

let interactor = MyInteractor()
interactor.myTestFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the matter from a little more distance. Let's start with your basic situation:

```
protocol CircuitUiEvent {}
enum MyEvent: CircuitUiEvent {
    case hello
}
protocol CircuitInteractor {
    associatedtype UiEvent: CircuitUiEvent
    func actionDispatcher(uiEvent: UiEvent)
}
```

That compiles, of course. Now, CircuitInteractor is a *generic* protocol, with an associated type called UiEvent. So now you try to inject *code* into CircuitInteractor with an extension:

```
extension CircuitInteractor {
    func myTestFunction() {
        actionDispatcher(uiEvent: MyEvent.hello)
    }
}
```

What are you trying to do here? `MyEvent.hello` is being passed at the point of the generic's parameterized type, i.e. where a UiEvent is expected. So evidently you are trying to *resolve the generic*. But this is code *in the protocol!* A generic protocol cannot resolve *itself!!!*

Here's a simplified form of what you're trying to say:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype Assoc
    var v : Assoc {get set}
}
extension P {
    mutating func f() {
        self.v = "hello"
    }
}
```

That's nonsense — the same nonsense as your code. P cannot set `v` of `self` (the *adopter* of P) to a string in attempt to make Assoc be String, effectively resolving itself.

Who *can* resolve the generic protocol? The *adopter* of the protocol:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype Assoc
    var v : Assoc {get set}
}
struct S : P {
    var v : String // <--
}
```